# Advanced boolean search of JSON files containing speech-to-text data?

Tags: xml, json, speech-recognition, subtitle, booleanquery

I have hundreds of automatic machine transcripts of video and audio files.  I have every transcript in five formats: JSON, XML, SRT, VTT, TXT.  (Click [here](http://pastebin.com/K4Mhwxgm) to see example files.)  The JSON and XML files contain the most comprehensive data, including speaker ID, confidence level, and timecodes.

I am looking for a way to mine or search this data to find words and phrases.  I need to be able to submit a Boolean search query, then click a result and *play the video/audio file at the timecode of the text result*.  The only necessary Boolean operators are NOT, AND, OR (just like an online search engine).  Example search: **("baseball bat" AND park) OR soccer**

I'm thinking of a fairly simple interface.

*Basic options:*

- Search box
- Minimum confidence level slider

*Ideas for advanced options:*

- Speaker: "Bob,Joe,Bill" (that is, speaker must be one of these)
- Maximum time allowed between words in AND search: X.X seconds
- Maximum time allowed between words in exact phrase search: X.X seconds
- Words in exact phrase search must have same speaker: ON/OFF
- Words between AND must have same speaker: ON/OFF
- Words between OR must have same speaker: ON/OFF
- Words between AND must be found within chronological order: ON/OFF
- Ignore punctuation: ON/OFF

Simply put, I need something like Agent Ransack with timecodes and, if possible, some miscellaneous options.  **I know this is a very specific and complex request.**  :)  Can you give me any leads on this idea?  I don't want to reinvent the wheel.  Which software/command line program/engine comes closest to being able to do all this?  Perhaps I can adapt it from there.

Thanks!

Comment: This is the wrong place to ask questions like yours. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement such a system on top of Solr/Lucene http://lucene.apache.org/solr, however, you need to get more experience to implement required features.

For open source implementation of speech archival and indexing you can check [Matterhorn](http://opencast.org/matterhorn/)

You can find details on Matterhorn speech indexing in [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/smarquard/open-textspeech-recognition-in-opencast-matterhorn)

However, this is not the only way to implement such functionality, you can also proceed with the language of your choice and simple tools. Ruby/PHP or Node.js will also work here.